# Manage email subscriptions lists

Tags: email, mailing-lists

I am after a way to manage email subscriptions to multiple people.

I would like to have a generic mailinglists@domain.com

Add to that distribution group.

People who are part of that distro group would automatically get all emails going to it.

I would like for them to manage it (be able to remove/add themselves)

Ideally I would have multiple aliases eg - mailinglists-sports@domain.com so people have the option to add themselves to only the lists they want.

Web interface would be best.

Does such a thing exist (do not want to set this up via internal ad / exchange)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mailchimp for your e-mail campaigns, E-mail groups etc.

Comment: I'm not after creating campaign emails but rather signing up for lots of them and then managing it (forward on to people automatically etc).